# Which PHP functions are necessary for TYPO3 6?

Tags: php, typo3

I just did a fresh install of TYPO3 6.1. The system environment check tells me, that some PHP functions are disabled on my server. I'm using Froxlor on my server to administrate domains and alike. Thus, I have complete control over this machine but I'm not sure which functions are really necessary. Some functions seem to be pretty dangerous to me, so I don't want to enable every function which are disabled on my box.

TYPO3 lists the following functions as disabled:

```
disable_functions=parse_ini_file passthru popen proc_close proc_get_status proc_nice proc_open proc_terminate shell_exec show_source system
```

Which should be definitely enabled for TYPO3 and which can stay disabled? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I really doubt anyone maintains a list of all the functions that TYPO3 uses. If unsure, why don't you just use your editor's "Find in Files" feature?

Comment: You should better put the webserver and the php process into an own chroot. Then you do not need to disable functions.

Comment: I'm using fcgi for this purpose. Every website has its own user and group, so the processes are separated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the function's use in the TYPO3 core and its system extensions. For the functions that are used it's up to you to decide whether you disable them or not. Some functionality will break if you disable them but it might be functionality that your installation doesn't need.

**Beware though that any of those methods might be used by any of the non-system extensions that you install!**

### Functions used

- **passthru** - used when generating thumbnails in the backend.
- **proc_close** - used, probably by a mailer class.
- **proc_open** - used, probably by a mailer class.
- **shell_exec** - used by the scheduler and by the RTE for spellchecking using Aspell.

### Functions NOT used

- parse_ini_file
- popen
- proc_get_status
- proc_nice
- proc_terminate
- show_source
- system

Comment: Thanks for this list. I just enabled all the functions you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

you should be able to edit a custom php.ini in froxlor; there you can re-enable functions. Try this [page](http://redmine.froxlor.org/projects/froxlor/wiki/FCGID_-_handbook) for instructions