# TYPO3 install tool says "Functions disabled!"

Tags: typo3

When I look into the `Install Tool > Basic configuration` for TYPO3 4.7, I see in Yellow a message `Functions disabled`and this text

```
disable_functions=pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
The above list of functions are disabled. If TYPO3 use any of these there might be trouble. 
TYPO3 is designed to use the default set of PHP4.3.0+ functions plus the functions of GDLib. 
Possibly these functions are disabled due to security risks and most likely the list would include a function like exec() which is use by TYPO3 to access ImageMagick.
```

What is it that I am missing in my configuration or in my server?

Comment: The check procedure is really ridiculous https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/SystemEnvironment/Check.php#L407 Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356236/which-php-functions-are-necessary-for-typo3-6

Answer (score 0):

Which PHP version you are using? TYPO3 4.7 needs at least PHP 5.3 as you can see [here](http://typo3.org/download/). Since these function above are available since PHP5, I guess you are running a lower version.

You can figure it out with `php --version`

Answer (score 0):

This is just an info, that some PHP functions are disabled in the active php.ini.
Fortunately there are no functions in this list, which TYPO3 relies in. 
You can just ignore it.

Comment: This is a no-issue :-) but if you insist, just check your php.ini and comment out this line (disable_functions=...), then restart apache.
To find out where your php.ini is, put phpinfo() in an empty php script and execute this. Somewhere near the top, you will find the path of this config file.